# jQuery - iframe inside iframe - ready vs load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Lets say I have the following:

default.asp:

```
<iframe src="frameOne.asp" id="myframeOne"></iframe>
```

frameOne.asp:

```
<iframe src="frameTwo.asp" id="myframe"></iframe>
```

frameTwo.asp:

```
<div id="hello">Test text</div>
```

Why does the following doesn't work (#1):

```
$("#myframeOne").load(function () {
         $('#myframeOne').contents().find('#myframeTwo').load(function(){
             $('#myframeOne').contents().find('#myframeTwo').contents().find('#hello').css('background-color','blue');
         });
    });
```

And this does apply the CSS?(#2):

```
 $("#myframeOne").load(function () {
             $('#myframeOne').contents().find('#myframeTwo').ready(function(){
                 $('#myframeOne').contents().find('#myframeTwo').contents().find('#hello').css('background-color','blue');
             });
        });
```

And this one doesn't(#3):

```
$("#myframeOne").ready(function () {
                 $('#myframeOne').contents().find('#myframeTwo').ready(function(){
                     $('#myframeOne').contents().find('#myframeTwo').contents().find('#hello').css('background-color','blue');
                 });
            });
```

As I understand the .load waits until the content of the iframe is loaded, so I don't quite understand why it behaves differently on the frames (why it works when apply on the outer frame, but not in the inner frame).

Comment: which version of jQuery you use?

Answer (score 1):

With iframes I work always with the load function. I've got problems with the ready function too so try to work with the load function.